# ssrs error - The attempt to connect to the report server failed

Tags: c#, windows, reporting-services, service

I'm running a windows network service on a clients server. It's job is to periodically check the database for any unprinted dockets, and print them to a network printer.

The issue is that whenever it attempts to print a report it gets the following error -

**The attempt to connect to the report server failed.  Check your connection information and that the report server is a compatible version.**

The ssrs web service can connect to the report server, and I have an instance of our main desktop application running on the server, and it can open reports.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

I found the issue. The server report URI was defaulting to localhost\ReportServer. This was fine when I ran on my own machine, but was causing an issue on the server (even though reporting services is on the server)

I changed it to a named instance, and it's working.
(serverReport.ReportServerUrl = new Uri("ServerName\ReportServer");)

Thanks